# DNSSEC - Jitter default value

Tags: domain-name-system, dnssec

does anybody know which is the default value for jitter when signing a zone??

Regards

Comment: It depends on the signing software you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a small zone your jitter value does not really matter. This is only useful if your signer is very slow or if your zone is enormous.

Comment: But is there a default value for that parameter?? I have a signature validity period of 1 hour. For example, one of my signatures starts at 20101027130000, but ends at 20101028134759 (when it should end at 20101028140000). So I was wondering that there must be a default jitter.

Comment: Sorry to be rude, but a signature validity of one hour is pure madness. It means you will have to re-sign every hour and, should anything go wrong, you will have at most one hour to fix it!